# Show image from private storage to rest api client in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, file-storage

I'm working on a laravel project and i have saved some pictures on a private storage folder .

This is config/filesystems.php :

```
'frontend' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/frontend'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage/frontend',
],
```

I want to show images to client using rest api ( my client is a flutter application ) .

I have tried using some methods of File Storage in Laravel but it wont help .

This is a method that i have tried but when i use it's url it says to me Not Found:

```
Route::get('/show-pic', function () {
    $pic = Picture::find(1);
    $link = Storage::disk('frontend')->url($pic->avatar);
    return response()->json($link , 200);
});
```

Also i dont want to get the content of pictures then return response containing content of picture ,

i just need url of picture .

Any suggestion will be helpful .

Thank you .

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same situation, trying to serve private files from Laravel to vue js. Both API and front are isolated projects. Not sure how to handle API headers when calling an image URL directly for the :src attribute

Comment: anyone solve this, I am facing the same issue, I want URL on my API

Answer (score 0):

please try :

```
$link = Storage::disk('frontend')->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
```

or

```
$link = Storage::disk('frontend')->path($pic->avatar);
```

Comment: the second one is showing me this :       E:\\Program Files\\Xampp\\htdocs\\newswall\\storage\\app/frontend\\pictures/1/5e202945af006scaledrdj.jpg

Comment: Ah!, but you want like https://www.yoursite.com/frontend/pictures/1/5e202945af006scaledrdj.jpg right ?

Comment: yeah i want it like this

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you can use environment variables as follows:

```
APP_URL='your_app_url'
```

And then in your controller, you may access the url like this:

```
$imageUrl = $('APP_URL').'/uploads/'.$imageFileName;
```

this assumes that your image files are stored in storage/uploads

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to display an image from private storage, in Laravel 9, I do it like this, and I think the same method could be used to make images available via rest API:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{base64_encode(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('private_disk')->get('path_to_image_in_private_folder'))}}" alt="">
```

private_disk configuration is in the filesystem.php config file. E.g.:

```
'private_disk' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/private_disk'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'private',
],
```

The above works for me even if I have a symlink to public storage added:

```
storage -> .../storage/app/public
```

Images are private and stored in

```
storage/app/private_disk
```

They are not publically accessible.

There are other ways of doing this, but I find this the easiest one for relatively **small images**.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to solve this issue :

Move your `frontend` folder inside `storage\app\public`

Then call

```
php artisan storage:link
```

And finally [you may use the `url` method to get the URL for the given file](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#file-urls)

```
Storage::disk('public')->url('frontend/' . $pic->avatar);
```

Comment: The problem is that i dont want these pictures be accessible to public